# AMONG US - Original problem using graph theory

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

I'm coming to you because i have a problem to resolve which includes a graph theory problem on the famous game : Among Us.
[Here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzBPM.png)

I've been thinking a lot about it, and i can't see which graph theory problem it refers to. I thought about a graph coloring problem, but i don't think it suites this problem perfectly, and there might be something else to try.

I've been able to code an algorithm which gives me 12 probable set of 2 impostors. But the instruction clearly talks about graph theory.

The problem is :
"Player 0 has seen player (1,4,5) / Player 1 has seen (0,2,6) / 2 HS (1,3,7) / 3 HS (2,4,8) / 4 HS (0,3,9) / 5 HS (0,7,8) / 6 HS (1,8,9) / 7 HS (2,5,9) / 8 HS (3,5,6) / 9 HS (4,6,7).

Player 0 has been reported dead so 1,4,5 may be an impostor.
Considering the second impostor hasn't seen 1,4,5, define a set of probable impostors.

Thanks to a graph theory problem, present how to find a set of probable impostors."

What i find with my algorithm : (1,3) (1,7) (1,8) (1,9) (4,2) (4,6) (4,7) (4,8) (5,2) (5,3) (5,6) (5,9) but i'm not using any graph theory algorithm so my question is what theory pb would fit and how.

Comment: Please edit the question to put the problem statement and your algorithm in the question.

Comment: Okay i have edited it now

Answer (score 0):

So there is not a particular Problem of Graph Theory that comes to my mind concerning this problem. However if you just create a Graph of each Player and connect each one with the players he saw, than you end up with a graph that enables you to quite quickly determine which Players may be the imposters.

So since the first subjects are those Players how have seen Player 0 you can just take their corresponding node in the graph and go to any other node that is connected to it (except node 0 of course). From these nodes on you can now go one more step to all connected nodes and they will be your secound suspect.

For example: Player 4 is a subject. His node is connected to Player 0,**3**,**9** ->
3 and 9 are connected with **2**,4,**8** and 4,**6**,**7**. -> This leaves us with 4 as a possible subject in collaboration with one of 2,6,7,8

Comment: Okay, that method is complementary to what i did which is :
by elimination
We go to each node connected to the dead player.
We consider the one we are on as an impostor, so the two others cannot be an impostor so we won't explore them,
now we go to the nodes connected to our alleged impostor, and all the players that he has seen cannot be impostors too
so the other nodes can be impostors

Comment: but since it neither is a graph theory problem way of resolving it, i don't know if it responds to the instruction :/

Comment: Maybe the term "graph theory problem" is in this context more refering to translating the problem in a graph problem and then trying to solve it. But for a certain Graph Theory Problem i am also clueless which answer is excpectet. If you know please update it here, i am also curious now :)

Comment: I will post an update if i find something relevant